# How to copy an EXE from a .net core app's bin directory into wwwroot without knowing the build configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have an `exe` being dropped into my `bin` directory however sometimes this `exe` will be dropped into `debug` or `release`.  Is there any way to - from a post-build event - say "hey, wherever we built this thing, copy it into the wwwroot folder"?

I see the following: http://www.benramey.com/2010/06/29/visual-studio-post-build-event-to-copy-dlls/

Where this code is used:

```
cd $(ProjectDir)
copy /y bin\debug\*.dll C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\{YOUR SHAREPOINT SITE DIRECTORY}\bin
```

However I want to not specify debug or release or `netcoreapp2.0` or `netcoreapp`:

[image]

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Use the provided macros.  You already used `$(ProjectDir)`.

`$(TargetPath)` will contain the complete path to the executable.
`$(OutDir)` will contain the output directory (relative).

Comment: This is not working.  `OutDir` and `ProjectDir` get me paths that do not include where the binaries are being dropped.  I'm getting `WebApp\wwwroot\exe\tokenizer.exe` for both - instead of the `bin` directory.  I want to copy from wherever it's being dropped (debug/release whatever) to wwwroot, know what I mean?